# How do I make it in a Django project so that after choosing an option in one form, the options in the other form are narrowed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to make my first project in Django which is a unit converter. I want to have a form where you can choose the type of units (like length, area, mass etc.). After choosing the type, then in the "to unit" and "from unit" fields there should ony be displayed units of the according type.

Here are the contents of my files:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class UnitType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Unit(models.Model):
    unitType = models.ForeignKey(UnitType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    conversion_factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def convert_to(self, value, to_unit):
        if isinstance(value, (int, float)) and isinstance(to_unit, Unit):
            conversion_factor = self.conversion_factor / to_unit.conversion_factor
            converted_value = round(value * conversion_factor, 4)
            return converted_value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input for conversion.")
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import UnitType, Unit

class UnitTypeForm(forms.Form):
    unit_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UnitType.objects.all())

class UnitConversionForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.DecimalField()
    from_unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.all())
    to_unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.all())
    def __init__ (self, unit_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UnitConversionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["from_unit"].queryset = Unit.objects.filter(unitType_id=unit_type)
        self.fields["to_unit"].queryset = Unit.objects.filter(unitType_id=unit_type)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UnitTypeForm, UnitConversionForm
from .models import UnitType, Unit

def unit_converter(request, unit_type = None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        typeForm = UnitTypeForm(request.POST)
        if typeForm.is_valid():
            unit_type = typeForm.cleaned_data['unit_type']
            form = UnitConversionForm(unit_type, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
                from_unit = form.cleaned_data['from_unit']
                to_unit = form.cleaned_data['to_unit']
                from_unit_obj = Unit.objects.get(name=from_unit)
                to_unit_obj = Unit.objects.get(name=to_unit)
                result = from_unit_obj.convert_to(int(quantity), to_unit_obj)
            else:
                result = None
    else:
        typeForm = UnitTypeForm()
        form = UnitConversionForm(unit_type)
        result = None
    return render(request, 'unit_converter.html', {'typeForm': typeForm, 'form': form, 'result': result})
```

unit_converter.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Unit converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Unit converter</h1>
  <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ typeForm.as_p }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
  </form>
  {% if result is not None %}
    <p>Conversion result: {{ result }}</p>
  {% endif %}

</body>

</html>
```

What I have doesn't work because after choosing a unit type in the form, the list for the conversion form is empty. However, when I modify my html's form section to something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ typeForm.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Choose">
</form>
  <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
  </form>
```

then after clicking the "Choose" button the option lists in the other form are as they should be, but there are a few problems: "This field is required" messages display above the form, then after completing the second form Django gives me the error:
"UnboundLocalError at /unit_converter/
cannot access local variable 'form' where it is not associated with a value"

So the question is, how can I let the user choose a unit type, then in the other form only display units of that type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one form. By sending a request to your backend with the selected `unit type` unique identifier, filter `unit` by it, return the data and manipulate the DOM to display it.

Starting by writing a new view that returns the data without reloading the page:

views.py

```py
def unit_values(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    unit_type = UnitType.objects.get(pk=data['unit_id'])
    units = list(Unit.objects.filter(unitType=unit_type).values("id", "name"))
    return JsonResponse(units, safe=False)
```

Add an URL path for it. I set its namespace as `unit-values`. And use JavaScript to do all the rest:

unit_converter.html

```
<body>
  <h1>Unit converter</h1>
  <form method="post" data-unit-values-url="{% url 'unit-values' %}">
    ...
  </form>
  {% if result is not None %}
  <p>Conversion result: {{ result }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <script>
    function getCookie(name) {
      ...
    }

    const clearSelector = (selector) => {
      for (let i = selector.options.length; i >= 1; i--) {
        selector.remove(i);
      };
    }

    const populateSelector = (selector, data) => {
      data.forEach(param => {
        let opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = param.id;
        opt.innerHTML = param.name;
        selector.appendChild(opt);
      });
    }

    const formElement = document.querySelector("form");
    const unitElement = document.getElementById("id_unit_type");
    const fromUnitElement = document.getElementById("id_from_unit");
    const toUnitElement = document.getElementById("id_to_unit");

    unitElement.addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
      const url = formElement.dataset.unitValuesUrl;
      const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
      const unitId = unitElement.value;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'unit_id': unitId }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      clearSelector(fromUnitElement);
      clearSelector(toUnitElement);

      populateSelector(fromUnitElement, data);
      populateSelector(toUnitElement, data);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Note the addition of the URL resolver pointing to the new view as data attribute of the form. Use [`getCookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) in order to attach `'X-CSRFToken'` to the request header. The rest is pretty much self explanatory by reading the code.

There are ways to improve this, wrapping the request into a try/catch and by filtering the selectors excluding the selected value from the other.